# How do I multiply a number input via a prompt?

Tags: javascript, multiplication, prompt

I am new to Javascript (actually this is my second day learning) and I have been trying to solve this but cant find any videos on the issue. I know how to multiply numbers specified by me in the function, for example:

```js
function doubleMe(a, b) {
  var result = a * b;
  return result;
}

var c = doubleMe(10, 10);

console.log(c)
```

but the problem I am having is I want the user to input a number via a prompt, and then multiply that number and alert the multiplication. I cant figure out how exactly to do this, the code I have is below:

```js
function doubleMe() {
  var numberOne = Number(prompt("What is your number?"));
  var double = numberOne * 2;
  return double;
}

var x = doubleMe();
alert(x);
```

Comment: I made a snippet and fixed the spelling of result.

Comment: Your code works. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @mplungjan The code seems to be working now that you edited it, what is it that I did wrong in the original code I posted? I tried to run in the f12 google chrome dev console as a snippet and it wouldnt work.

Comment: The first code had a misspelled `result` that I fixed, the second code should work and is working as is. I just pasted it into the console and it works

Comment: So in the code that requires a prompt there was no issue? @mplungjan thank you very much for the help! I have been wracking my brain over this for the last hour and couldnt figure out why it wasnt working. Thank you very much.

Comment: The prompt code works as expected